# CFSocketSetAddress fails

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sockets, macos-carbon

I have a problem with `CFSocketSetAddress()`. The first time I call it, it works just fine.
If I clean up everything associated with the socket and attempt to open it again on the same port I get a `CFSocketError` of -1 (`kCFSocketError` - very descriptive).

I'm presuming I didn't clean up the previous socket correctly. I'm cleaning up all the FileDescriptors and calling `CFSocketInvalidate` and `CFRelease` on the `CFSocketRef`. Is there anything else I need to do to clean up the existing socket so that the socket can be reopened?

Comment: Check `errno` for a more specific error code.

Comment: Have you set the socket option SO_REUSEADDR when you created the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this always happens. Post to StackOverflow and then figure it out about 5 mins later.

Answer: I needed to call closeFile on the `NSFileHandle` associated with the socket.